# Removing node in XML array

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an incoming SOAP message I need to delete certain record based on some search condition like field "ActCode" . If this filed is not matching with given list of values then i need to delete that particular element "a:empAccountsResponse" from Array "empResult". My XSLT is not working as expected.

Please let me know where it is causing the issue.

Input XML:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://example.com">
   <s:Header></s:Header>
   <s:Body>
      <empResponse xmlns="http://example.com">
         <empResult xmlns:i="http://example.com" xmlns:a="http://example.com">
            <a:empAccountsResponse i:type="b:empResponse" xmlns:b="http://example.com">
               <a:status>Active</a:status>
               <a:ActCode>JHO</a:ActCode>
               <a:pId>WQT</a:pId>
            </a:empAccountsResponse>
            <a:empAccountsResponse i:type="b:empResponse" xmlns:b="http://example.com">
               <a:status>Active</a:status>
               <a:ActCode>TDD</a:ActCode>
               <a:pId>TDD</a:pId>
            </a:empAccountsResponse>
         </empResult>
      </empResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Output:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://example.com">
   <s:Header></s:Header>
   <s:Body>
      <empResponse xmlns="http://example.com">
         <empResult xmlns:i="http://example.com" xmlns:a="http://example.com">
            <a:empAccountsResponse i:type="b:empResponse" xmlns:b="http://example.com">
               <a:status>Active</a:status>
               <a:ActCode>JHO</a:ActCode>
               <a:pId>WQT</a:pId>
            </a:empAccountsResponse>
         </empResult>
      </empResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

XSLT Code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="empResult">
<xsl:if test="ActCode = 'JHO' or ActCode = 'FFG'">
<xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Start with an [identity transform](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#copying) and then add another empty template matching `inquiryAbout[not(AccType='PTC') and not(AccType='TRA')]` (or `inquiryAbout[not(AccType=('PTC','TRA'))]` if you're using XSLT 2.0+). Come back with what you've tried if you're still having issues.

Comment: i just updated my Input XML and expected out put and also gave my XSLT code. Let me know where is issue in my code.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your template is matching `empResult` and checking for a child named `ActCode`.

The first thing wrong with that is that `empResult` would never match anything because `empResult` is in the default namespace `http://example.com`.

The second thing wrong with that is that even if you accounted for the default namespace, and the fact that `ActCode` is in a namespace (it should be `a:ActCode`), the only children of `empResult` are `a:empAccountsResponse`.

What you need to match is `a:empAccountsResponse`...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:a="http://example.com">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="a:empAccountsResponse">
    <xsl:if test="a:ActCode = 'JHO' or a:ActCode = 'FFG'">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I also think it's cleaner to add an empty template to remove elements instead of doing a copy of the ones you want to keep...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:a="http://example.com">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template 
    match="a:empAccountsResponse[not(a:ActCode='JHO') and not(a:ActCode='FFG')]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Example in action: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyyiVhn